# Push the menu down

Tags: css, menu, background

Hey Guys I have this little problem. I building a site and I want to push down the menu inside the a div that have a cover background. Problem is that when I do that ( I set a top margin to #mainheader) I get a white line I don't want to have.

http://legacybydesign.tv/exceed/idea.html

What do you think I should do?

Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding padding to `#bg_intro`.
*(I tried this in the console in your page and worked nice)*

For example:

```
#bg_intro {
padding: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
/*rest of CSS */
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Itay, then it just changes the vertical parameter. OP just wanted distance in the top. But, sure just `30px` all round works fin if OP likes :)